# "Data View" component which is added inside the Display.aspx form will not be shown in modern interfaces

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, data-view-web-part, aspx, dataview

I want to build something similar to having Master/Details lists inside sharepoint online. so i follow an approach mentioned on this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zJ4jR3TQF0), which mainly do these steps:-

1. created 2 lists (Master & Details)
2. then inside the Details list they added a lookup field to reference the Master list.
3. using SP designer, inside the Master list's display form, they added a Data View component to reference the Details list, as follow:-

[image]

now i tried this appraoch inside my test team site and i got this result, which worked well, keeping in mind that it only took me less than an hour to do. so this is a fast appraoch to implement an acceptable result, here is the result inside the Master item display form:-

[image]

But i am facing these 2 issues and 1 question:-

1. Inside the Master display form, i was not able to move the Master item's metadata info (created, modified, content type info), to be below the Data View items. not sure if this is actually possible.
2. if i access the Master item's display form in modern interface, then the Data View component will not be shown !! so can i conclude that modern interfaces will skip any Data View component added to the list forms? if this is the case, then i need to re-think of using Data Views, as we are trying to use the modern interfaces as much as possible.
3. i am not sure if i can add a Data View component in edit mode, inside my Master list's edit form, which will allow me to add Details items, while editing the Master item?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you consider paid solutions, I'd recommend trying [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/). It has [List or Library](https://plumsail.com/forms/list-or-library/) control which allows you to put related items from another list into a modern form and edit them right from the parent form. The product is much cheaper than the amount you'd spend on developing this feature by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not sure, but I don't think it's possible.
2. Definitely not possible. SharePoint designer, Data view en Webpart connections are not part of the modern ui. [Webpart connections are just announced for Q1 2019.](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-roadmap?featureid=33133)
3. Don't know.

If you want this in Modern UI you could check if you could get something like this to work with PowerApps if you want to go No Code and host the PowerApp in a webpart on the page. Otherwise you need to develop your own SPFX webpart.

Comment: i have a trial period to use power apps ... but i am not sure if power app can help in building master/details inside our modern UI??

Comment: If you have Office 365, you have a license for PowerApps, although you need to check the limitations. Master detail should be possible with PowerApps:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/how-to-do-master-details-proposal-products-prices-3-screens/td-p/99